# UPS C# API- create return Label with initial shippmet?

Tags: c#, api, label, ups

I have working code for UPS API, the only thing I cant do is to ask for a returning label as well as the shipping label.

On UPS site you can request a return label for 50 cents, and it only billed when sent.

Any ideas what value I should change?

Thank you,
Idan.